# JavaScript ignore commas inside ChartJS data field pulled from csv that data has commas and is enclosed by double quotes

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, chart.js

I have been looking for the answer without finding the right solution yet... but I am pulling data for ChartJS from a CSV file, and within that CSV file one of the columns has data that has commas in it... here is an example of the data in the CSV file:

```
"Group","Number of Times","Status"
"Group1","1,377","Handled"
"Group1","877","Not-Handled"
"Group2","132,377","Handled"
"Group2","878","Not-Handled"
"Group3","14,268","Handled"
"Group3","1,231","Not-Handled"
```

I am able to get the CSV pulled into ChartJS, but the commas in the "Number of Times" fields are throwing off the data and causing it to not display properly when it has a number that is large enough to have a comma (i.e. if the number for "Group1" is 877 then the bar appears, but the number that is 1,377 fails to parse and display properly).

I have tried all sorts of solutions, such as doubling the quotes around "Number of Times", adding them to data, trying to join the field so I ignore the commas (which seems silly), etc., but cant seem to solve why it wont just ignore the commas inside the double quotes, or not break ChartJS all together. Here is part of the code that I think is relevant:

```
var fullFD = "01December2020";
var file = 'http://localhost/Daily_Chart_' + fullFD + '.csv';
d3.csv(file).then(makeChart);
    function makeChart(alerts) {
    var groupsLabel = alerts.map(function(d) {return d["Group"]});
    var numbersData = alerts.map(function(d) {return +d["Number of Times"]});
    var statusColors = alerts.map(function(d) {return d["Status"] === 'Handled' ? '#F15F36' : '#19A0AA';});

            var chart = new Chart('chart', {
                type: 'horizontalBar',

                data: {
                    labels: groupsLabel,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            data: numbersData,
                            backgroundColor: statusColors,
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

I am new to JavaScript and ChartJS, so please don't think too poorly of me :)  Any suggestions or have I missed someone else who asked this exact same question and solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is this line:

```
var numbersData = alerts.map(function(d) {return +d["Number of Times"]});
```

If you log the value of numbersData to the console you'll see something like that:

> Array(6) [ NaN, 877, NaN, 878, NaN, NaN ]

As you already figured it has to do with the comma inside your number. As you're prepending a **+** before returning `d["Number of Times"]`, it ultimately tries to convert the string e.g. 1,377 into a number, fails (because of the comma) and thus returns NaN - which means **Not a Number**.

One easy fix is replacing all the commas of numbers inside your .csv file by a dot (**.**).

> 1,377 -> 1.377

If you don't want to modify the .csv file itself, you can replace all occurences of a comma by a dot using javascript:

```
var numbersData = alerts.map(function(d) {let num=d["Number of Times"]; num=num.replaceAll(",","."); return Number(num);});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. What is your question?

Comment: Can it be removed instead? 
Would changing it to a decimal create a different number 23626 vs 23.626?

What you provided works to change it, and it seems to be on the right track, but can I just remove it in this same line that you provided?

Comment: I think I got it after I looked at it a second time. Thanks for the solution. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: Here is what I ended up with...

var numbersData = alerts.map(function(d) {let num=d["Number of Times"]; num=num.replaceAll(",",""); return Number(num);});

Comment: You're completely removing the comma? Well, so 1,377 shouldn't be a decimal number at all?

Comment: Yes... it is one thousand three hundred seventy seven... I suspect you are using European formatting :)

Comment: Aaah hehe, now everything makes sense. I'm aware of the formatting but somehow I got stuck in thinking it must be a decimal number. Glad you got it working now!